# I am trying to insert data to CoreData entity in the middle of array, but it does not work

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, storyboard

The goal of my app is to help users to learn the words of another language

I use for that two CoreData entities:
WordEntity with attributes ru and eng. There are I want to save words in Russian and English.

And QuizEntity with attributes to, from and name. As I store words in

```
    var words: [WordEntity] = [],
```

I need to remember indexes for every quiz and name to show for user.

I have CoreDataManager class.

```
    class CoreDataManager{
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext
    
        private init(){
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            fetchWords()
            fetchQuizzes()
        }
    
        static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    
        //MARK: - WordEntity
    
        var words: [WordEntity] = []
    
        //MARK: - QuizEntity
    
        var quizzes: [QuizEntity] = []

        func fetchWords(){
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<WordEntity> = WordEntity.fetchRequest()
        
           do {
                let words = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                self.words = words
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        func fetchQuizzes(){
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<QuizEntity> = QuizEntity.fetchRequest()
        
            do {
                let quizzes = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                self.quizzes = quizzes
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

I want to implement function that allow user to add words to the quiz. To do that I tried to insert word into `words[]` and move index for quiz.to(is last index of words in this quiz).

Example(pseudocode):

```
    words = ["cat","audi","tesla","school"]
    quiz[0] ={
        .from = 0
        .to = 0
        name = "animals"
    }
    quiz[1] ={
        .from = 1
        .to = 2
        name = "cars"
    }
    quiz[2] ={
        .from = 3
        .to = 3
        name = "education"
    }
    For example I want to insert "bmw" to quiz2. words array will be something like -             ["cat","audi","tesla","bmw","school"] and quizzes will be: 
    quiz[1] ={
        .from = 1
        .to = 3
        name = "cars"
    }
    quiz[2] ={
        .from = 4
        .to = 5
        name = "education"
    }
```

I was trying three different ways.
This is the best in my opinion:

```
    /*As i use tableViewController, I pass indexOfQuis where i want to add word.
    In the top example it is 1. dataWords is data that i want to insert,
    countOfWords means how much words I want to insert and From is index quiz[indexOfQuiz].to .*/
    func addWordsToQuiz(indexOfQuiz: Int,dataWordsRu: [String], dataWordsEng: [String], countOfWords: Int, from: Int){
        
            guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "WordEntity", in:     context) else { return }
            let taskObject = WordEntity(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        
            taskObject.setValue(dataWordsRu[0], forKey: "ru")
            taskObject.eng = dataWordsEng[0]
            //insert Entity
            words.insert(taskObject, at: from + 1)    
            //Moving index for quiz.to(is last index of words in this quiz)
            for quiz in indexOfQuiz..<quizzes.count{
                if quiz == indexOfQuiz{
                    quizzes[quiz].to = Int64(quizzes[quiz].to + 1)
                }else{
                    quizzes[quiz].from = Int64(quizzes[quiz].from + 1)
                    quizzes[quiz].to = Int64(quizzes[quiz].to + 1)
                }
            }
        
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        
        }
```

Below I will show you `words[index].ru` before this function and after.
And it works almost well, except ...

```
Optional("1")
Optional("2")
Optional("3")
Optional("4")
Optional("5")
Optional("6")
Optional("7")
Optional("8")
Optional("9")
```

**This is array of words before inserting.**

```
Optional("1")
Optional("2")
Optional("3")
Optional("4")
Optional("5")
Optional("6")
Optional("qwe")
Optional("7")
Optional("8")
Optional("9")
```

**This is after. I inserted "qwe" word.**

**But if I restart my project or close and open app on simulator it looks like**

```
Optional("1")
Optional("2")
Optional("3")
Optional("4")
Optional("5")
Optional("6")
Optional("7")
Optional("8")
Optional("9")
Optional("qwe")
```

I don't know why the position was changed and my question is how can I fix it?

Comment: CoreData isn’t ordered. You can use sort descriptors to add order/sort an array. You can add an index attribute to the object if you really need an index and sort from that.

Comment: @loremipsum "You can add an index attribute to the object if you really need an index and sort from that." I thought at the begging of project about it, but it was not necessary. Now it sound like a plan, but maybe somebody knows another solution, if not, I will do that. Thank you for answer.